# Prove that A-(B⋃C) = (A-B)⋂(A-C)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Please let me know if this proof is right, I think it is but I still want confirmation

```
A - (B⋃C)
= A ⋂ (B⋃C)'           [X-Y = X⋂Y']
= A ⋂ (B'⋂C')          [(X⋃Y)' = (X'⋂Y') - De-Morgan's Law]
= (A⋂A) ⋂ (B'⋂C')      [A = (A⋂A) - Idempotent Law]
= A ⋂ A ⋂ B' ⋂ C'
= A ⋂ B' ⋂ A ⋂ C'      [Commutative Law]
= (A⋂B') ⋂ (A⋂C')
= (A-B) ⋂ (A-C)        [X⋂Y' = X-Y]
```

Hence, Proved

Let me know what you think

Thanks...

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: This proof is perfect.

Comment: Thank You @pg_star and James.

Comment: I know, but there's  a certain amount of time before you can accept the answer. Just waiting for the time to be over :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct (Good Work!) but note it is not complete in terms of justification; you need to note that fact that $\cap$ is associative (it may seem obvious to you that the unjustified steps will be understood, but when you're new to proofs, it's best to not cut corners):

```
A - (B⋃C)
= A ⋂ (B⋃C)'                                         [X-Y = X⋂Y']
= A ⋂ (B'⋂C')                                        [(X⋃Y)' = (X'⋂Y') - DeMorgan's Law]
= (A⋂A) ⋂ (B'⋂C')                                    [A = (A⋂A) - Idempotent Law]
= A ⋂ A ⋂ B' ⋂ C'                                    [Associative Law]
= A ⋂ B' ⋂ A ⋂ C'                                    [Commutative Law]
= (A⋂B') ⋂ (A⋂C')                                    [Associative Law]
= (A-B) ⋂ (A-C)                                       [X⋂Y' = X-Y]
```

Comment: Honestly, I was removed that at the end, thought I was wrong, should have included it, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you got it right, earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is fine, although I would advise that you use MathJax in future.

Comment: Thank You... :)

Comment: You're welcome, @Rajdeep_Sundhu.